# Google Map API Key not loading in SmartGWT Application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt

I am trying to integrate Google Maps API with my smartgwt application here is what I implemented in .gwt.xml

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.GoogleMaps' />
```

.html File

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='my_key'&sensor=true"/>
```

I am generating Browser Key on the google console with a referer */application_name/*

The application works good on the dev mode and localhost but the same does not work on deploying the app on clients server....It throws the message like "Google has disabled the use of Google Map API for this application. Either the key is invalid or you are not authorized to use the Google Map Javascript API............"

I am held up with this since 3 days. any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is seems that you registered the wrong URL with the key. The URL does only work with very specific URLs, plus *localhost* for testing. The correct way to solve this is to find and authorize the right URLs to use your client ID. See the [Google Map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/troubleshooting_auth).